# Rails says that "role", a property I made doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, web-applications, dbmigrate

I clearly made the role for users (as you can see down below) but it says it doesn't exist. Help please? By the way, you can see how I'm hardcoding myself.

app/controllers/application-controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base


  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  helper_method :current_user

  def current_user
      @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def require_user
      redirect_to '/login' unless current_user
  end

    def require_admin
        redirect_to '/' unless current_user.admin
    end
end
User.create(first_name: "Johnny", last_name: "Appleseed", email: "j.appleseed@example", password: "MY AWESOME PASSWORD THAT NOBODY KNOWS", role: "admin")
```

db/migrate/20160109170743_create_users:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :users do |t|
            t.string :first_name
            t.string :last_name
            t.string :email
            t.string :password_digest
            t.string :role, :default => "reader"
            t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

app/controllers/users-controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @user = User.new
    end

    def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)
        if @user.save
            session[:user_id] = @user.id
            redirect_to '/'
        else
            redirect_to '/signup'
        end
    end

    private
        def user_params
              params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :role)
        end
end
```

Comment: can you post the error msg as well?

Comment: Are you sure you migrated the `db`?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specific error message, I can only speculate that your error is here:

```
def require_admin
   redirect_to '/' unless current_user.admin
end
```

Regardless of the attributes you have in your model / db, you'll only get instance methods you've *defined*. You don't have `admin` in your `User` object, thus making `current_user.admin` invalid.

You'd need to use the following:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   def admin? 
      self.role == "admin"
   end
end

current_user.admin? #-> true / false
```

Whilst the question mark isn't required, it denotes the evaluation of an object's properties (`true / false`).

---

As an aside, you may want to look at adding an [`enum`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) to your `User` model:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   enum role: [:reader, :admin]
end
```

This will give you a series of [`instance` & `class` methods](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/) to better help your logic:

```
@user = User.find params[:id]
if @user.admin?
  ...

@admins = User.admin
#-> collection of "admin" users
```

To do it, you'll need to change your `role` column from `string` to `integer`

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that you use boolean for the column role.

User.rb

```
 def admin?
    self.role == true
 end
```

so you can do

```
redirect_to '/' unless current_user.admin?
```